# Value in code is different than text in excel file

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

I have a specific problem with ClosedXML. In code, when I get the value of a cell in clasic way via Cell(x,y).Value I get a value "3.805", as string.

Problem is, that in excel file, this cell is formatted as "Text" and the value seen by user is "3,805", with comma, not with dot.

This problem occurred, when a user wanted to replace dot with comma in excel file with search and replace feature, and changed all dots in column for commas. These commas are visible for user in cells, but code reads them as dots. After manually changing the dots for commas in excel, code reads them with commas, as it should be.

Has someone experienced this behavior? Text value in excel appears with commas, when formatted as text and code with closedxml reads them as string with dots?

Comment: The value is the same. What you see is how it's rendered bay Excel based on the end user's locale. Don't try to change it, you'll only break the spreadsheet. Excel formulas work with the stored value, not the displayed text. They also use the end user's locale to parse text. If you try to "fix" the displayed text by storing the value as text instead of a number, it will still be parsed using the end-user's locale and result eg in `3805` instead of `3.805` or vice versa

Comment: Hello, I get that numbers with decimals are handled this way, but this is formatted as text, on different cells made this ways is also a warning, that number is written as text, and they behave normal. Only problem is after search and replace dot with comma in excel on text.

Comment: The problem is *caused* because the numbers were stored as text. That's why Excel warns you too. `Only problem is after search and replace dot with comma in excel on text.` you broke the spreadsheet. There was no problem before that. *Don't* try to change how numbers are displayed. They aren't broken

Comment: In our local (sk-SK) the decimals are separated by comma, not a dot. So it didn't know it was a number before replacing the dot for comma, and all columns are formatted as text, because on some rows there is a valid text, not a number as text.

Comment: Same here in Greece. *Don't try to replace dots and commas in the first place*. If the user does this, tell them to undo. If you generate that file *don't* use strings for numbers, use the correct type - decimal, float or double

Comment: Individual cells are not affected by what other cells in the same column contain. Excel isn't a database. If you store a number in `Value`, and ensure the cell's style is *not* set to a text format, there won't be any problem.

Comment: I think i finally got your point. I tried debugging and changing format for number and examined the value, inner text, rich text and other properties of closedxml cell class and with number the dot is always there, but read value and rich text is with coma. Thank you for your time.